# Need help Parsing String in java

Tags: java

I am getting Messages from Server So that I need to Parse the Contents of the Messages.
Currently I received the Message and converted it into the String specified below,

```
Lat:+1290.9890N

Long:+9098.987890E

Spd:90km/h
```

So from the above String, I need to get the Value of Lat,Long and speed ..How to do that in Java..Thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: There is one obvious component that belongs to all your inputs: `:`. Use that to break the strings and then decide what to do with the left and the right part.

Comment: seriously man i have my keen interest in WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED SO FAR ??

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, use substring function http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html. Try by your self.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split, substring or other ways to do it. I would recommend to use pojo for this to avoid any issues in processing string like Sting index out of bounds other possible exceptions. It will be cleaner and easier to manage as your message seems pretty static in its format.

Answer (score 0):

Create a string builder for each line.

Iterate through each existing string.

Call isDigit() on each item in the string.

If isDigit == true, append the digit to the string builder.

Cast the string builder to a long

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Scanner and call findInLine() with a Pattern regular expression that will only find floating point numbers e.g. (0..9)*.(0..9)*